# PHP show custom result from serialize data

Tags: php, serialization

I insert data to database using serialize method like this :

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{
     i:0;s:14:"docs/name.docx";
     i:1;s:39:"docs/php-advanced-master.zip";
     i:2;s:39:"docs/php-master.zip";
}}
```

Now with this function, show/print list of file name:

```
function _file_list_($id,$type){

    $files = DataAccess::fetch("SELECT * FROM " . NEWS_FILES . " WHERE news_id = ? AND type = ? ",$id , $type ); 

    if (count($files) > 0) {

        $list_files = unserialize($files[0]['url']);
            $count  =   count($list_files[0]);
            for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
                $files_show[]  =   array($list_files[0][$i]);
            }
        return $files_show;

        }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

This worked for me and result is :

```
docs/name.docx
docs/php-advanced-master.zip
docs/php-master.zip
```

But, I need to show/print only `docs/php-advanced-master.zip` from list.

how do i print/show this ?

Comment: `$files_show = _file_list_($id,$type); echo $files_show[1];` is not good enough?

Comment: If you have a specific reason to only show that very filename, you can probably formulate a description of that reason -  and either tell us, or write some code yourself (once you have formulated out the differentiating factor).

Comment: Are there any specific conditions for you to display only "docs/php-advanced-master.zip". It's difficult to answer your question with a consistent solution without further details.

Comment: @ReneKorss: file list is dynamic! i think work with sql `WHERE ` id or filename from serialize data.

Comment: @mario: i think before print file list we need to choose result using `WHERE` in sql. ie: using `filename` or serialize `id`.

Comment: You can't have a `WHERE` clause filter it, because you store an *opaque blob*. MySQL can neither read nor extract from the serialize dump.

Comment: @mario: now, how do?!

Comment: Actually you can filter with where, but it's not efficient. The serialized data is stored as a string in the database. It seems that you are using the field "url" to store the serialization data. You can append this to your SQL query:
`AND url like "%php-advanced-master.zip%"`

Comment: @arvind.d: I think your `array_walk` method better than mysql search using `like`. can u fix your answer!

Comment: @Perspolis, I corrected the answer, can you try now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_walk and use whatever logic you need to only show the file you require. The following code will call your function and process the result. It will check if there is a filename with "php-advanced-master.zip" in the list and output it.

```
$files = array_unique(_file_list_($id,$type), SORT_REGULAR);
array_walk_recursive($files, function ($value) {
    if (false !== stripos($value, "php-advanced-master.zip")) {
        echo $value;
    }
});
```

However, if you want to filter the serialized data directly from your SQL query. Assuming your serialized data is stored in the "url" field, you can modify your function like this:

```
function _file_list_($id,$type, $filenameFilter){

    $files = DataAccess::fetch("SELECT * FROM " . NEWS_FILES . " WHERE news_id = ? AND type = ? AND url like '%?%'",$id , $type, $filenameFilter); 

    if (count($files) > 0) {

        $list_files = unserialize($files[0]['url']);
            $count  =   count($list_files[0]);
            for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
                $files_show[]  =   array($list_files[0][$i]);
            }
        return $files_show;

        }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Perspolis, I edited the answer for the first solution. There was an error in the code. It should work now.

Comment: `Warning: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\modules\download.php on line 31

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\modules\download.php on line 32
Array` show this error in loops. (in case three error)

Comment: @Perspolis, in your `_file_list_` function you should have the following line: `$files_show[] = $list_files[0][$i];` instead of `$files_show[]  =   array($list_files[0][$i]);`. You are inserting a single value array inside an array, which in not efficient, unless you have a very specific reason to do so. This is why you are getting the error with stripos. However, if you still want to use your function as is, you can use the following code instead: `array_walk_recursive($files, function ($value) {
 if (false !== stripos($value, "php-advanced-master.zip")) {
  echo $value;
 }
});`

Comment: I also edited the answer to reflect the `array_walk_recursive` modification to work with your original `_file_list_` function.

Comment: now worked!! but i have little problem. if i have similar filename, in result i see two or many filename like : `docs/php-downloader-master.zip` `docs/php-downloader-master.zip`

Comment: @Perspolis, I changed the first line in my answer with `$files = array_unique(_file_list_(null, null), SORT_REGULAR);` to filter the filename list by uniqueness before walking through the array to search for the filename. Also, please avoid adding further questions in the comments. If you need help with other parts of your code, either create another question or update the original question and accept the answer if it solved the original question.